# Comparing string value to .text() value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare values stored in an array to .text() values and then add class if they match. Currently this is outputting the array, and the text values but boolean is returning false.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexmattorr/71evjcpm/)

**Code**

```
        var comMem  = [];
        i = 0;
        $(this).find(".com-member ul li").each(function() {
            comMem[i++] = $(this).text();
        });

        $(".board-name").each(function() {
            var boardName = $(this).text();
            console.log( boardName );
            console.log( comMem );
            if(boardName == comMem) {
                $(this).addClass(active);
            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing a string to an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

```
//Use .map()
var comMem = $(".com-member li").map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get(); //Get return you an array

//Since you want to iterate hence use li using descendant selector
$(".board-name li").each(function() {
    var boardName = $(this).text();

    //Use indexOf() to check it exists in an array
    if(comMem.indexOf(boardName) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass("is-active");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/k3fa5ndb/)</kbd>

References [`$.fn.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`$.fn.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `boardName` with a array so, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var comMem  = [];
    i = 0;
    $(".com-member li").each(function() {
        comMem[i++] = $(this).text();
    });

    $(".board-name").each(function() {
        var boardName = $(this).text();
        console.log( boardName );
        console.log( comMem );
        if(comMem.indexOf(boardName) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass("is-active");
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a string to an array at

```
if(boardName == comMem) {
```

You need to use indexOf()

```
if(comMem.indexOf(boardName) > -1)
```

See [MDN's indexOf() Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)